# Create Salesforce Case object with nested relationships using REST API

Tags: api, rest, salesforce

I am attempting to create a new Case object using the REST API but need to find out how to format the JSON body to pass in nested SObjects.

It's not apparent in the Docs, and I can't seem to find any examples. Anyone have any pointers or have done this before?

The SF web UI uses a text lookup field to set the (related) Contact and Account, and I need to figure out how to either bypass the need for a lookup or embed the SObjects of the related records in the JSON.

```
[{"message":"The value provided for foreign key reference Contact is not a nested SObject","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out by simply setting the AccountId and ContactId attributes on the new Case object.

Comment: Could you please tell me what was the REST API URI you used for creating a new case?

Comment: same here, could you please post a code snippet? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I also haven't seen any documentation about this, but if you look at the object metadata returned by the REST API for any standard object, it seems that the suffix 'Id' is appended to any field of type "reference".  For example, Case has OwnerId, LastModifiedById, CreatedById, etc.  This suffix is not present in the field names displayed in the browser interface.  The WSDL for the SOAP API includes both the ID as a simple element of type "ID", as well as a complex child element for nesting the actual record.